# Repeating animation inside an each function

Tags: jquery

I am presenting images one by one using each and animate. After the last image has been shown, i would like to repeat showing all images again after a short pause of fx 6 seconds.

Ive tried combinations with setTimeout, but i must be missing something - here is the code im using:

```
var viewport_height = $(window).height() - 100;
$('section#slide_art').css({ 'height' : viewport_height });

$('img.img_slide_this').each(function(slide_this) {
    var get_img_height = $(this).height(); 
    $(this).css({ 'width' : '0', 'margin-left' : '50%', 'height' : get_img_height, 'max-height' : viewport_height });

    $(this).delay(3000 * slide_this).animate({ 'opacity': '1', 'margin-left' : '0', 'width' : '100%' }, 700, 'swing')
        .delay(1500).animate({  'height' : get_img_height, 'width' : '0', 'margin-left' : '50%'}, 700, 'swing').fadeOut();          
});
```

**UPDATED AS AN ANSWER** 
I managed to solve my question with a few modifications - im posting in case others might have interest:

```
function run_slider() {

        var viewport_height = $(window).height() - 100;
        $('section#slide_art').css({ 'height' : viewport_height });

        $('img.img_slide_this').each(function(slide_this) {         
            var get_img_height = $(this).height(); 
            $(this).css({ 'width' : '0', 'margin-left' : '50%', 'height' : get_img_height, 'max-height' : viewport_height });

            $(this).delay(3000 * slide_this).animate({ 'opacity': '1', 'margin-left' : '0', 'width' : '100%' }, 700, 'swing')
                .delay(1500).animate({  'height' : get_img_height, 'width' : '0', 'margin-left' : '50%'}, 700, 'swing');                    
        });

        // 2 x images
        // setTimeout(run_slider, 7500); 

        // 4 x images
        setTimeout(run_slider, 15000); 

        // 8 x images
        // setTimeout(run_slider, 30000);

} 

run_slider();
```

Comment: you add a recursive callback function at the end of the animation

Comment: Can you add an example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your list of images is not changing, then the best way to organise what you want may be a function that animates a single image, and then triggers the next animation in the callback. Here's an example:

```
    var viewport_height = $(window).height() - 100;
    $('section#slide_art').css({ 'height' : viewport_height });

    var images = $('img.img_slide_this');
    var animateImage = function(index) {
        if (index > images.length) { return; }
        var image = $(images.get(index));
        var get_img_height = image.height();
        image.css({ 'width' : '0', 'margin-left' : '50%', 'height' : get_img_height, 'max-height' : viewport_height });

        image.animate({ 'opacity': '1', 'margin-left' : '0', 'width' : '100%' }, 700, 'swing')
            .delay(1500).animate({  'height' : get_img_height, 'width' : '0', 'margin-left' : '50%'}, 700, 'swing')
            .fadeOut(function() {
                if (index < images.length - 1) {
                    animateImage(index + 1);
                } else {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        animateImate(0);
                    }, 6000)
                }
            });     
    };
    animateImage(0);
```

Notice the callback added to the final fadeout, either triggering the next image as soon as the fadeout is done, or waiting then triggering the first image again.

It looks to me as though your final animation and fadeout are running simultaneously, so if this doesn't look quite right, you may want the callback attached to the last animate, rather than the fadeout.

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive answer. I understanding what you are trying do, which will eliminate the use of each. However i found a working solution with my current code which only takes a few alterations - im posting as an update